# What conversions are taking place here?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Which conversions take place when evaluating the following expressions?

```
char cval;
int ival;
float fval; 
// Assume all 3 have been set to correct values...
a) if(fval)
b) double dval = fval + ival; 
c) dval + ival + cval;
```

My thoughts:

a) I assume `if` needs a `bool` value, so the `float` gets implicitly casted to `bool`.

b) I assume that `fval` is promoted to `double` and `ival` is converted to a `double`, and then they are added.

c) First, `ival` is converted to a `double`.  Then `dval + ival` gets evalutated, which is of type `double`.  Then `cval`...I don't know if it gets converted to `double` directly, or if it it is promoted to `int` first. Anyway, after that step the temp value dval + ival is added to that `double`.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: All three have undefined behaviour, because they involve reading from uninitialised values.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong, but I can't recite the standard on those points. However, I would say that you know the details better than most C++ programmers.

Comment: @Mankarse The result is undefined, not which conversions are taking place.

Comment: @Mankarse true. However do not look at that, assume they have been properly initializied, it is just about the conversions taking place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) `fval` is contextually converted to `bool`.

---

In cases `b` and `c`, the "*usual arithmetic conversions*" apply, meaning:

b) `ival` is converted to `float` and (using a special rule, rather than the "*usual arithmetic conversions*") `fval + ival` is converted to `double`.

c)  `ival` is converted to `double`, `cval` is converted to `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the devil is in the details with questions like this, always possible you miss something.

A) Actually I found the answer on stackoverflow([Is if(double) valid C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767162/is-if-double-floatx-valid-c-code)): everything in an if is converted directly to boolean.

B) First iVal is converted to float, then added to fVal, and then converted to double. The expression is fully evaluated/typed before the assignment.

C) Left to right order will be applied to the + operators. So iVal is converted to double, then added to dVal and then the same happens with cVal, so directly to double.